# Magento 2 - Custom payment module

Tags: extensions, magento2, payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I'm trying to build a custom Payment module, but it's very hard to get things to work because there's no real documentation yet. There are a few example extensions, but these are all outdated.

What I got working:

- The user selects the Payment method
- The user can select his bank from a list of dutch banks
- After the user presses 'Place order' the user is redirected to the success page

What I cannot figure out to do:

- Redirect the user to payment provider after 'Place order' is pressed
- I should provide a redirect url to the payment provider where the user is redirected to after payment.

  - The ability to fetch the response of the Payment provider and show the success page to the user.

I'm working on this for days now, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Redirection can be maintained by **place order button handler**.
For example please refer to Paypal Express checkout integration, here are several components required:

1. Payment Method form template - 
   where you need to define a click event handler which processes a **place order button**.

***Example***
*app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html*

`<button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="click: placeOrderAction, enable: (getCode() == isChecked())"
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Continue to Gateway'"></span>
                </button>`

2. View model(renderer) - a model for defined template.

***Example*** *app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal-express-abstract.js*

```
/** Redirect to Gateway */
        placeOrderAction: function () {
                this.selectPaymentMethod(); // save selected payment method in Quote
                setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

3. Define setPaymentMethodAction - which will place order and then redirect user to a gateway.

***Example*** *app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method.js*

And
*"The ability to fetch the response of the Payment provider and show the success page to the user."*.

The suggestion depends on Payment Gateway a communication pattern between Store and Payment Gateway. But as I understand your case is *Redirect to Payment gateway side and then back to store*.

This can be gained by defining a response action and route responsible for handling requests from Payment Gateway with redirect logic to *Success page*

Answer (score 1):

First you can review https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-provider. But it's looks outdated.

Also, you can read http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already found these examples but unfortunately they are both outdated.

Comment: Any Updated link or full sample tutorial