# redirect to iframe on custom payment method on magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I want to make a redirect after i configure IframeConfigProvider.
I have the cgi_url on config.xml and call it inside getConfig() at IframeConfigProvider and still i cant make the redirect.

After a press the "Place Order" button -i get a success page .

I know i have the block who call to iframe.phtml and i suppose its need to be use after IframeConfigProvider is set and call inside /etc/frontend/di.xml.

I really googling out and check braintree and razorpay extension but i cant really get a clearly answer.

Note: there is a topic who related to my question [Magento 2 - Custom payment module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91515/magento-2-custom-payment-module) but i'm not sure the solution because i cant make the connection to iframe.phtml and IframeConfigProvider().

I even try to config my sarig-method.js but still - none of the action really works.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/refaelgold/f614153c468d1a6e9212f66942c22b31/raw/813c0f0be1ce1b0c98dfbf86744b730408d157e3/sarig-method.js

(sorry about the gist but i cant really paste my code here with the special tags)

Any help?

Comment: Looking for the same.

Comment: You need to use the IframeProvider. i finish this modules months ago .

Comment: Can you answer your own question please? This may help others also.

Comment: I created an xml and controller and use IframeProvider for the admin fields and create phtml file change the js as well .. thats a LOT for do a simple iframe and i wish i had the time to write down all the solution but i have a lot of staff to do...

Comment: You have the code somewhere in github?

Comment: i'm also looking for same.